Yet another question on time dilation on basic special relativity (with code)
I've been trying the book Computation Physics and came up with the following exercise:

Exercise 2.4: A spaceship travels from Earth in a straight line at relativistic speed v
to another planet x light years away. Write a program to ask the user for the value of x
and the speed v as a fraction of the speed of light c, then print out the time in years
that the spaceship takes to reach its destination
(a) in the rest frame of an observer on Earth, and
(b) as perceived by a passenger on board the ship.
Use your program to calculate the answers for a planet 10 light years away with v=0.99c.

Ok. A basic exercise on Special Relativity. I came with the following code:
def compute_t(x, v):
"""Computes the proper time and the relativistic time for given inputs x and v"""

lorentz_factor = 1/sqrt(1 - v**2)
t_relativistic = x/v
t_proper = t_relativistic*lorentz_factor

return t_relativistic, t_proper

I mean, there is more code than this but this is the important part concerning special relativity. Inputting x = 9.5 light years and v = 0.95c it returns the following:
For the given x and v, 10.000 years has passed on Earth, while 32.026 years has passed on the spaceship

And I got confused.
Am I computing time dilation wrongly?
Isn't it supposed to be shorter in the reference frame of the spaceship?
Time dilation formula is:
$$ t' = \dfrac{t}{\sqrt(1 - v^2/c²)} $$
For the reference frame on Earth, t is just $$ t = x/v $$
Which means, $$ t' = \dfrac{x}{v} \times \lambda $$ where $ \lambda $ is the Lorentz factor. Since $ \lambda > 1$ then $t` > t$ indeed. But maybe I'm wrong and the proper time, that is the time passed in the reference frame of the moving object is actually the inverse, that is $\dfrac{t}{\lambda}$ which in this case 10 years would have passed in the reference frame of Earth while only 3.1 years would have passed in the reference of the spaceship.
I think I'm misusing the equations. Which one is right?

When in doubt, do a Lorentz transformation. There two events $(t, x)$ going from event $A$ to event $B$:
Leaving Earth:
$$ A = (0, 0) $$
Arriving at destination:
$$ B = (L/v, L) $$
So the elapsed time on Earth is:
$$ \Delta t = B_t - A_t = L/v $$
Now boost those to the rocket frames:
$$ A' = (0, 0) $$
$$ B' = \big(\gamma(B_t - vB_x), \gamma(B_x - vB_t)\Big)
=  \big(\gamma(L/v - vL), 0\big) $$
so
$$ \Delta t' = \gamma L(\frac 1 v - v) = \gamma
\frac L v (1 - v^2) = \gamma L/v/\gamma^2 = \Delta t/\gamma $$
So: Always do the Lorentz transformation$^1$, and only look at coordinate differences, not coordinate values.
[1] In this case, you may not need the LT, and just use the fact that the invariant interval is, well, invariant:
$$\Delta s^2=(B_t-A_t)^2-(B_x-A_x)^2 = \Delta s'^2=(B'_t-A_t')^2-(B'_x-A'_x)^2$$
Ofc, since you're using python, you should make a Minkowski class with t, x attributes, and the overload dunder abs and dunder sub.
Whether you want separate classes for affine Events and normal old 4-vectors is up to. That's what I would do.
